# Microsoft appcenter and upload APK without integrating their SDK on Ionic 3 app

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, hockeyapp, visual-studio-app-center

I can upload an APK to the hockey app. But I cannot see any such option on Microsoft [appcenter](https://appcenter.ms). I need to upload Ionic 3 APK to there. But it seems I cannot do that without integrating their SDK with my Ionic 3 app. Do you know any method to directly upload APK there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily upload an `apk` to `AppCenter` by the following steps:

`Note:` I got this info through Appcenter chat.

> Select your app --> Go to distribute --> Click on release --> Select
>   new release

[image]